# How can i establish the trust relation in bitbucket and git on server

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

I want upload my repo to the bitbucket

When i do this

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then i get this error from remote shell

```
(gnome-ssh-askpass:51926): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

How can i fix that

I have already setup the ssh keys from here 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run that from a commnd line that isn't running under X.  That's why it can't open the display and ask you for a passphrase for your ssh key.

You should be able to fix it by [disabling gnome-ssh-askpass](http://kartzontech.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-disable-gnome-ssh-askpass.html).